# Improve the speed for vector multiple matrix multple vector

Tags: matrix, julia

I am calculating vector multiply vector and vector multiply matrix multiply vector in Julia.

The orignal code is below.

```
using LinearAlgebra
n=10000
vector1 = randn(n,1)
vector2 = randn(n,1)
matrix1 = randn(n,n)
matrix2 = randn(n,n)
want1 = transpose(vector1)*matrix1*vector1
want2 = transpose(vector1)*vector2
```

I would like to improve the speed for the calculation, so I am using mul! in LinearAlgebra.

```
w1 = similar(vector1')
mywant1 = similar(want1)
mywant2 = similar(want2)
mul!(w1,vector1',matrix1)
mul!(mywant1,w1,vector1)
mul!(mywant2,vector1',vector2)
```

When n is large, for example n=100000, the calculation without mul! is faster. I am just wondering if there is anway to improve the speed of the calculation as well as save memory?

Comment: Firstly, use vectors instead of nx1 matrices. They are not the same. `rand(n)`, not `rand(n, 1)`. Then you can use `dot(v, X, v)` instead of `v'*X*v` and also `dot(v1, v2)`.